# JQuery Toggle of orderd list

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am trying to show and hide (toggle) an `<ol>` when a click a link using JQuery.
My HTML is

```
 <ol id="sortable" class="sortable">
    <li>
       <div>
          <span class="drag-image groupimage">&nbsp;</span>
          <a class='expand'>{{ portfolio_group.name }}</a>
       </div>
     <ol style="display: none; margin:0px" id={{ portfolio_group.id }}>
         <li>
            <div class="patent-div">
               <span style="" class="drag-image patentimage">&nbsp;</span>
               <a class="patent-name" href='{{ path('v2_pm_patents_edit', { 'patentId': patent.id }) }}'>{{ patent.patentName }}</a>
            </div>
     </ol>
 </ol>
```

As the inner ol is hidden and I want to make it toggle when I click on the link with class = expand.

What I tried so far

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.expand').click(function() {
        $(this).nextAll('ol').eq(0).slideToggle('fast');
    });
```

});

But its not working 
Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.nextAll()` function looks at siblings of the element(s) in the jQuery object it's called on. However, the `<ol>` you want to toggle doesn't look like it's a sibling of the `<a>` element that's triggering the click event, but instead is a sibling of the `<div>` element that contains the `<a>`.

You can traverse up the DOM to the parent `<div>` using the `.parent()` function, then call `.nextAll()`:

```
$(this).parent().nextAll('ol').eq(0).slideToggle('fast');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JcWes/).

```
$(".expand").click(function() {
   $(this)
       .parent()
       .nextAll('ol')
       .eq(0)
       .slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: It won't work, because `.children()` only goes down a single level in the DOM, and the `<ol>` you need is contained within an `<li>`.

Comment: Thanks Sam for the quick reply

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that nextAll only searches the dom for siblings of the current selector, however your example shows that the OL you wish to expand is seperated from the clicked item contained by a div.

I've made a solution on JSfiddle which, providing the html structure of your example doesn't change in production (namely the OL you wish to expand always immediately follows the parent 'div' that contains the clickable link) should work.

The link to the fiddle is here -

http://jsfiddle.net/2LQJe/11/

The code I used is here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.expand').click(function() {
        $(this).parents('div').next('ol').slideToggle('fast');
    });

});
```

The reason this works is that we have to first go up the dom tree to find an element that is a sibling of the one which you wish to expand, in this case a div, and then iterate through this sibling set, although this solution isn't very flexible i'll admit.

*Edit* I also noticed that your html structure has a small error in that the li immediately following the ol you wish to expand isn't closed, to rectify this you should put a closing () tag after the "patent-div" node.